# Simplifying the boolean expression: A ^ B * C

Tags: boolean, computer-science, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I've been trying to simplify the 
**Boolean expression:** `A ^ B * C` for some time now. I'm able to first simplify it down to: `A * ~B + ~A * B * C` but after that I can't seem to simplify it further. Using an online simplifies, it says that it simplifies to `(A + B) * (A + C) * (~A + ~B)` but why is that? And what laws are used to simplify it to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the precedence of the operators. Normally AND comes before XOR and it is `A XOR (B AND C)`. Some programming languages evaluate expressions strictly from left to right when not using parentheses, resulting in `(A XOR B) AND C`, assuming you are using `^` for `XOR` and `*` for `AND`.

Your simplification seems to be going for the latter variant but normally in boolean algebra you'd evaluate the AND first:

```
  A * ~(B*C) + ~A * B * C
= A * (~B + ~C) + ~A * B * C
= A * ~B + A * ~C + ~A * B * C
```

It's been a while that I've worked with boolean expressions like this, so I don't know if there can be made any further simplifications (or even if mine are correct).

And are you sure, you wrote down the result of the online simplifier correctly? Because the term `(A + B) * (~A * ~B)` evaluates to `A * ~A * ~B + B * ~A * ~B = 0 + 0` and therefore the whole term evaluates to `false`. This is all assuming that there is the following precedence of operators: NOT > AND > OR. If the last term in their solution is `(~A + ~B)` it would make more sense and evaluate to your term `A * ~B + ~A * B * C`, it just is its conjunctive normal form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm sure that I typed it in correctly on the simplifier; however, I did mistype the expression. The online simplifier outputs: (A + B) * (A + C) * (~A + B)

Comment: How is that answer simpler than the original form? The original form looks pretty simplified to me already.

Comment: @TomMozdzen The original form might be easier to read but normal forms (the results) use only `AND` and `OR` (and `NOT`) and can be used to apply automated theorem proving and other techniques.

Comment: @sven hoek I was misreading ^ as OR. The word "simplification" was vague to me. If he said transforming, it would have been clearer to me sooner.